# How to make a list with item subdescriptions?

Tags: lists

I want to make a list  that has roughly the structure as shown:

[image: one list item]

It should have item description, and under that optional subdescription, with text to the right of both of them.

Is it possible to do so with some custom list environment, or should i look to the tables instead?

Comment: Please post a compilable code of what you've tried. In your image, what is supposed to be the subdescription? This isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `enumitem` package to define a new list type. Here I defined a `subdescription` list environment based on `itemize`. In this environment (and *only* there) the `\item` command is redefined to take a mandatory argument (the year in your example) and an optional argument which, if given, will be placed under the mandatory argument. If the optional argument is used, it is expected that the description will be at least two lines. If it is not the case the optional argument will overlap on the next item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{subdescription}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[subdescription]{
    labelwidth=9mm,
    before=\changeitem,
    after={\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem}}
}
\newcommand*{\changeitem}{%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand{\item}[2][]{\olditem[\stackitem{##2}{##1}]}
}
\newcommand*{\stackitem}[2]{%
    \textbullet \textbf{#1}%
    \ifx#2{}\else%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{%
            \raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{#2}%
        }%
    \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{subdescription}
    \item[(09)]{1939}
        German invasion of Poland. In two weeks polish resistance is broken by the Wehrmacht.
    \item{1939} Beginning of the war.
    \item{1945} End of the war. 
\end{subdescription}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just what i needed. As a follow up question - how can i make sure that item subdescription is, for example, split in 2 lines? Place \\ in it?

Comment: @Srv19 As it is implemented here, it will always be on two lines: in the ``subdescription`` environment, the mandatory argument of ``\item`` is the first line, and the optional one is the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % itemize and enumerate options
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[1939-09] German invasion of Poland. In two weeks Polish resistance is broken by the Wehrmacht. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach does not allow `09` to be located below `1939`. If that is essential, you could use the `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    1939 & German invasion of Poland. In two weeks Polish resistance is broken by \\ 
    (09) & the Wehrmacht. \\ 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `description` envirement, withe the `multiline` style, for which I defined the `parright` alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem} % itemize and enumerate options

\SetLabelAlign{parright}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{{}\raggedleft#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries0000},style=multiline, align =parright, leftmargin=\labelwidth+0.5em]
    \item[1939 -09] German invasion of Poland. In two weeks Polish resistance is broken by the Wehrmacht.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]